Polars 0.19 AttributeError: 'Expr' object has no attribute 'replace'
I'm working with Polars version 0.19.15. In the documentation for version 0.19 there is an example for replace(). However, it raises an AttributeError:
import polars as pl
pl.__version__
# '0.19.15'

# An example from the 0.10 docs:
df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 2, 3]})
df.with_columns(pl.col("a").replace({2: 100}).alias("replaced"))

# AttributeError: 'Expr' object has no attribute 'replace'

In a related question, an answer suggests using replace() instead of map_dict().
What am I doing wrong?

map_dict should work for that version. I don't think replace was there until 0.19.16 (Although, using such an old version of Polars is likely not recommended at all.)

Ah, ok. Thanks! map_dict() works. I thought that API would have been static for all 0.19. I'm afraid I can't affect the version. I have to recheck.
